# Google Analytics: Is it possible to show all events in one table with event Category, Action and Label as columns

Tags: google-analytics

Iv been tracking events ga('send', 'event', 'blah', 'blah1', 'blah2');
say I also send ga('send', 'event', 'blah3', 'blah4', 'blah5');

is there a table in google analytics where I can see

```
| Category | Action | Label | total events |
|----------|--------|-------|--------------|
| blah     | blah1  | blah2 |            1 |
| blah3    | blah4  | blah5 |            1 |
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this through Custom reports, because standard reports will only, at the moment, allow for only 2 simultaneous dimensions. Just go to Customization in your Admin page, and then create a new custom report like so:

**Edit Feb. 9/15:** Custom reports now allows for up to 5 dimensions! Whoop!

[image]